# Antd tabs is not responsive on mobile using touch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, antd

I have a react component where i have different categories listed in horizontal manner and based on the selected category i am showing the details in cards below. This is working fine for everything except when its on mobile phone i can't able to scroll with touch which normally a user would do.

This is the code that i have written,i have tried applying different css styling's but its not working. I want to know is it achievable in antd tabs or not.

```
    <Tabs className={styles.forumTabWrap} onChange={onHandleTab}  >
              {tabsContent.length > 0 &&
                tabsContent.map((item, index) => {
                  return (
                    <TabPane
                      className={styles.forumTab}
                      tab={
                        <Card
                          hoverable
                          style={{ height: 150, width: 160 }}
                          cover={
                            <>
                              <div className={styles.tabIconDefault}>
                                <Image
                                  src={item.iconDefault}
                                  alt={item.tabContent}
                                  width={160}
                                  height={106}
                                />
                              </div>
                              <div className={styles.tabIconHover}>
                                <Image
                                  src={item.iconHover}
                                  alt={item.tabContent}
                                  width={160}
                                  height={106}
                                />
                              </div>
                              <div className={styles.tabIconActive}>
                                <Image
                                  src={item.iconClick}
                                  alt={item.tabContent}
                                  width={160}
                                  height={106}
                                />
                              </div>
                            </>
                          }
                        >
                          <p className={styles.tabIconContent}>{item.tabContent}</p>
                        </Card>
                      }
                      key={index}
   
                    >
                      <CommentBox
                        activeCategory={item.tabContent}
                        categoryData={categoryData}
                        error={error}
                        redirectTab={activeTab}
                      />
                    </TabPane>
                  );
                })}
            </Tabs>
```